# Displaying a certain number pattern using any nested loop in C++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++. I have got a homework question in which I have to print this pattern using any nested loop structure. But I am unable to complete it. I can only print the first line of the program as it is shown in the output. Please advice me into the right direction.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 2;
    int num3 = 3;
    int num4 = 4;
    int num5 = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        num1 = num1*num1;
        num2 = num2*1;
        num3 = num3*1;
        num4 = num4*1;
        num5 = num5*1;
        std::cout << num1 << "*#" << num2 << "*#" << num3 << "*#" << num4 << "*#" << num5 << "*#" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Actual output:

```
1*#2*#3*#4*#5*#
1*#2*#3*#4*#5*#
1*#2*#3*#4*#5*#
1*#2*#3*#4*#5*#
```

Expected output:

```
1*#2*#3*#4*#5*#
1*#4*#9*#16*#25*#
1*#8*#27*#64*#125*#
1*#16*#81*#256*#625*#
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] by adding the adequate `#include`s and fixing the declaration of `main()`?

Comment: Two loops nested: Outer loop: each iteration prints a line. Inner loop: each iteration prints the number (and `*#`), just one number per iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't have to modify the variables you use to print the desired pattern.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 3, num4 = 4, num5 = 5; // "const" because I won't modify their values.
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) { // Pay attention: equal result of "for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)"
        // In each iteration there will be a pow between numX and i.
        // First iteration: pow(num1, 1) => 1, pow(num2, 1) => 2, ...
        // Second iteration: pow(num1, 2) => 2, pow(num2, 2) => 4, ...
        // Third iteration: pow(num1, 3) => 3, pow(num2, 3) => 8, ...
        cout << pow(num1, i) << "*#" << pow(num2, i) << "*#" << pow(num3, i) << "*#" << pow(num4, i) << "*#" << pow(num5, i) << "*#" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, because the values of num1, num2,... used only once in the program, and because it is very small program, you can skip their declaration part and use straightly their values ("Hard Coded"):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    cout << pow(1, i) << "*#" << pow(2, i) << "*#" << pow(3, i) << "*#" << pow(4, i) << "*#" << pow(5, i) << "*#" << endl;
}
```

Pay attention that for normal program, "Hard Coded" is definitely not recommended and may have very ban influence on your future work on this code, but it's an option.

---

EDIT:

As L.F mentioned, the std::pow method has a mainly drawback in case of integers / single precision variables (int, long int, unsigned, char, etc..). in those cases, you can always get better performance by using `num * num` instead of `pow(num, 2)` or `num * num * num` instead `pow(num, 3)`.

To make your code run faster, you should use self power calculation, like this:

```
int my_pow(int num, int n) {
    int res = 1;
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        res *= num;
    }
    return res;
}
```

The following code check the times difference between `my_pow` and `std::pow` (gcc, ubuntu 16.04):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    cout << "Current i: " << i << endl;
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); // Start clock (take the current time - when the selected code is about to start)
    pow(1, i); pow(2, i); pow(3, i); pow(4, i); pow(5, i);
    auto stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); // Stop clock (take the current time - when the selected code finished)
    cout << "std::pow [nanoseconds]: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start).count() << endl; // Print clock results

    start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); // Start clock (take the current time - when the selected code is about to start)
    my_pow(1, i); my_pow(2, i); my_pow(3, i); my_pow(4, i); my_pow(5, i);
    stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); // Stop clock (take the current time - when the selected code finished)
    cout << "my_pow [nanoseconds]: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start).count() << endl; // Print clock results

    cout << endl;
}

----Output:

Current i: 1
std::pow [nanoseconds]: 19375
my_pow [nanoseconds]: 99

Current i: 2
std::pow [nanoseconds]: 14416
my_pow [nanoseconds]: 105

Current i: 3
std::pow [nanoseconds]: 3581
my_pow [nanoseconds]: 125

Current i: 4
std::pow [nanoseconds]: 614
my_pow [nanoseconds]: 134
```

Comment: It would be nice if you also mention the potential drawbacks of `pow`.

Comment: @L.F. you definitely right! post edited.